# Invoke Async Funcs

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I've made a nice controller helper in my MVC project that allows me to return similarly structured result payloads when I make any ajax request. It looks like this:

```
    public static JsonNetResult Responsify<T>(Func<T> func)
    {
        AjaxResponse response;
        var result = new JsonNetResult
        {
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };

        try
        {
            var resp = func();
            response = AjaxResponse.SuccessResponse(resp);
            result.Data = response;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            response = AjaxResponse.ErrorResponse(e.Message);
            result.Data = response;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

and it gets used like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonNetResult Link(LinkInstruction instruction)
    {
        return ControllerHelper.Responsify(() => _linkHandler.Link(instruction));
    }
```

where `_linkHandler.Link` is not async.

My issue is I have some async handlers that I would like to invoke using this pattern and I can't figure out how to await the function. I've tried Task.Factory.StartNew as well as wrapping the lambda in async/await and I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: Where is the `async` in your code? I dont see any.

Comment: Are you saying that `func` can point to an async function?

Comment: OP - You have to clarify what you mean. Do you mean you want both synchronous and asynchronous versions?

Comment: Lets imagine that I have a method on _linkHandler that's called LinkAsync. I want to use a similar pattern as I have above, but I can't with the Responsify static method I have now.

I've tried things such as 

`ControllerHelper.Responsify(async () => await _linkHandler.LinKAsync(instruction));` 

to no avail.

I also tried making a ResponsifyAsync method but I didn't know where to go with that.

Comment: I've moved my comments to an answer so you can hopefully make more sense of the solution I'm proposing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a version of `Responsify` - call it `ResponsifyAsync` - that specifies that the passed `Func` must return a `Task<T>` (therefore meaning you can `await` it):

```
public async static JsonNetResult ResponsifyAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> func)
{
    ...
}
```

This would do much what your current function does, but would `await func()` instead of just executing it.

You must then pass a `Func` delegate that returns a `Task` to this method. When calling an `async` library in the delegate, since the async method you're calling already returns a `Task`, this will simply take the form:

```
var x = await ResponsifyAsync(() => _someClass.MyMethodAsync(someParameter));
```

Or, if the method is parameterless...

```
var x = await ResponsifyAsync(_someclass.MyMethodAsync);
```

I'll let you flesh out the method but this format should set you off on the right lines.

Comment: Yes - which is why you need `Responsify` and `ResponsifyAsync`.

Comment: Thank you, what can I await within the body of my function though? You can't await func.DynamicInvoke, that's where I'm lost.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Ant, it worked like a charm. I thought I had to use DynamicInvoke for some reason (probably because I was previously using a Delegate and not a Func as my argument). Updating my question with the final answer :)

Comment: No problem - though SO convention is to leave questions in questions and answers in answers ;)